# Tar is not extracting to another directory with -C

Tags: tar

I'm trying to download latest ffmpeg from [here](https://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/) and extract the ffmpeg file to `/usr/bin` but no matter what I do I can't make the file go there!

My command to download and extract the file

```
wget -q https://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/releases/ffmpeg-release-amd64-static.tar.xz -P /tmp

tar -xf /tmp/ffmpeg-release-amd64-static.tar.xz  --no-anchored 'ffmpeg' -C /usr/bin/ --strip-components=1
```

Obs: I want only the file there, not folders!

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried placing `-C /usr/bin/` **before** the file argument `'ffmpeg'`?

Comment: @steeldriver that works! I'm so dumb :( should I delete this question?

Comment: It's a valid question I think (the order dependence of the `-C` switch is documented, but perhaps not familiar to many)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As noted in `man tar`, the `-C` option only affects operations that come after it:

> ```
> -C, --directory=DIR
>         Change  to DIR before performing any operations.  This option is
>        order-sensitive, i.e. it affects all options that follow.
> ```

So for example moving the `'ffmpeg'` file argument after the `-C` should work:

```
tar -xf /tmp/ffmpeg-release-amd64-static.tar.xz  --no-anchored --strip-components=1 -C /usr/bin/ 'ffmpeg'
```